# nested styles in less, style parent AND childrens

Tags: css, less

how can I set styles for an element and some of his descendants? Like for example:

```
.datepick-month-header, .datepick-month-header select, .datepick-month-header input {
background-color: black;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
```

}

in less documentation I've found nested styles, who works well, but I want to select BOTH $this and the descendants.

```
.datepick-month-header {

     select, input { // this selects "select" and "input", 

}
```

}

how can I set all the three elements (parent, childrens) in one declaration?

thank you

Comment: Have you tried what you're proposing? Simply declaring multiple selectors seperated by a comma should work. What problem are you having?

Comment: absolutely, I get this: .datepick-month-header select,
.datepick-month-header input {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
} it doesn't style the parent

Comment: It should work fine. I just ran the same code against the less compiler at http://lesstester.com/ and i get the result I expected.

Comment: @JamieDixon I want also to style datepick-month-header, but don't know how to declare it, something like: $this, select, input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use & to reference the parent context, eg.

```
.a {
  &, & .b .{
  }
}
```

Comment: I can see how this solved your problem @Daniele but I still don't quite understand why a simply chained decleration wasn't working for you. If I do .a, .a .b {} this works fine for me. I wonder if I missunderstand your question or perhaps something is going awry for you.

Comment: I know there are dozens of way to get this, but I've asked for the sake of knowledge ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know I can do this, but get redundancy code in output css:

```
.datepick-month-style {

background-color: @datepickMonthHeaderBackgroundColor;
color: @datepickMonthHeaderColor;
font-weight: bold;

}

.datepick-month-header {

.datepick-month-style;

select, input {

    .datepick-month-style;

}

}
```